# Azure Apache Spark groupby clause throws an error

Tags: azure, apache-spark

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark#analyze-nyc-taxi-data-with-a-spark-pool) section of a tutorial on `Apache Spark` from Azure team. But when I try to use `BroupBy` function of `DataFrame`, I get the following error:

**Error**:

> NameError: name 'TripDistanceMiles' is not defined

**Question**: What may be a cause of the error in the following code, and how can it be fixed?

**NOTE**: I know how to group by the following results using Spark SQL as it is shown in a later section of the same tutorial. But I am interested in using the `Groupby` clause `on the DataFrame`

**Details**:

a) Following code correctly displays 100 rows with column headers `PassengerCount` and `TripDistanceMiles`:

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://testcontainer4synapse@adlsgen2synspsetest.dfs.core.windows.net/NYCTripSmall.parquet', format='parquet')
display(df.select("PassengerCount","TripDistanceMiles").limit(100))
```

b) But the following code does not group by the records and throws error shown above:

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://testcontainer4synaps@adlsgen2synspsetest.dfs.core.windows.net/NYCTripSmall.parquet', format='parquet')
df = df.select("PassengerCount","TripDistanceMiles").limit(100)
display(df.groupBy("PassengerCount").sum(TripDistanceMiles).limit(100))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the TripDistanceMiles into double quotes. Like

```
display(df.groupBy("PassengerCount").sum("TripDistanceMiles").limit(100))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. That was my bad. I forgot to enclose that column with double quotes. It works now.